# Создание анимации через потоки на Android

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, canvas, анимация

Здравствуйте, стоит задача, на языке Java под ОС Android нужно написать задачу: создать снеговика и сделать так, чтобы его составляющие объекты меняли цвет с разной скоростью. Смена цветов должна быть реализована в потоке.
У меня получилось написать код, но не понимаю, как именно эта анимация должна в этот поток помещаться. Вот собственно полный код, написан в Eclipse:

```
package ru.ucheba;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;

public class Zadanie2 extends Activity {
    int a = 255;
    int r = 100;
    int g = 0;
    int b = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new Panel(this));

    }

    class Panel extends View {
        public Panel(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint p1 = new Paint();
            p1.setStyle(Style.FILL);

            p1.setARGB(a, r, g, b);
            canvas.drawCircle(270, 170, 70, p1);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                r--;
                SystemClock.sleep(10);
                invalidate();
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
                p1.setARGB(a, r, g, b);
                g--;
                canvas.drawCircle(270, 310, 100, p1);
                SystemClock.sleep(20);
                invalidate();
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < 30; k++) {
                p1.setARGB(a, r, g, b);
                b--;
                canvas.drawCircle(270, 510, 150, p1);
                SystemClock.sleep(40);
                invalidate();
            }
        }

        class Task extends Thread {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Чем заполнять метод `run()` понимаю, но ругается либо на `canvas`, `p1`, или `invalidate()`. Прошу помощи

Comment: Слово "ругается" можно применить к сварливой жене. У программистов конкретные ошибки, решение которых исходит именно из их точности (в чем именно ошибка), а не абстрактных заявлений о неопределенных "ругательствах". Пока вам можно посоветовать только - в ответ на ругательства сказать пару добрых слов, это поможет сгладить конфликт или тоже наругать в ответ, это поможет снять напряжение ...

Comment: По `p1` и `canvas` у вас очевидно ограничена область видимости переменных. Стоит ознакомиться с передачей значений в вложенный класс вообще и новый поток в частности.

Comment: Обдумайте интервалы задежки между кадрами анимации. 10 мс это 100 fps, не каждый девайс такое потянет :)

Answer (score 3):

Ваш код принципиально неверен. В методе `onDraw()` нельзя вызывать `sleep()` и `invalidate()`. Это все вместе с изменением переменных `argb` должно происходить в отдельном потоке, а метод `onDraw()` только отрисовывать экран в соответствии с их состоянием.

```
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        p.setARGB(a, r1, g1, b1);
        canvas.drawCircle(270, 170, 70, p);

        p.setARGB(a, r2, g2, b2);
        canvas.drawCircle(270, 310, 100, p);

        p.setARGB(a, r3, g3, b3);
        canvas.drawCircle(270, 510, 150, p);
    }
```

Перенести в конструктор и сделать переменной класса:

```
p = new Paint();
p.setStyle(Style.FILL);
```

В `run()` меняйте `rX, gX, bX` как вам надо и вызывайте синхронно с основным потоком `invalidate()` когда надо перерисовать.

Answer (score 1):

Выполнил вот таким образом, может кому-то поможет. Думаю, этот код можно написать гораздо лучше. Поэтому кто сможет, укажите на ошибки, буду благодарен.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class Zadanie2 extends Activity {
    int[] Colo = { 10, 20, 30 }; // массив со значениями исп. для цветов                            // снеговика
    public Thread myThread1, myThread2, myThread3; // создание переменных для потоков
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new Panel(this)); // использование класса Panel в качестве активити

        myThread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int znak = 1;
                while (true) {
                    if ((znak > 0) && (Colo[0] > 250)) {
                        znak = -znak;
                    }
                    if ((znak < 0) && (Colo[0] < 5)) {
                        znak = -znak;
                    }
                    Colo[0] += znak;

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(30);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        myThread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int znak2 = 1;
                while (true) {
                    if ((znak2 > 0) && (Colo[1] > 250)) {
                        znak2 = -znak2;
                    }
                    if ((znak2 < 0) && (Colo[1] < 5)) {
                        znak2 = -znak2;
                    }
                    Colo[1] += znak2;

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(30);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        myThread3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int znak3 = 1;
                while (true) {
                    if ((znak3 > 0) && (Colo[2] > 250)) {
                        znak3 = -znak3;
                    }
                    if ((znak3 < 0) && (Colo[2] < 5)) {
                        znak3 = -znak3;
                    }
                    Colo[2] += znak3;

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(30);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        // запуск потоков
        myThread1.start();
        myThread2.start();
        myThread3.start();
    }

    class Panel extends View {
        public Panel(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            float w, h, cx, cy, radius; 
            // переменные, для адаптивного расположения снеговика
            w = getWidth(); // считывает ширину
            h = getHeight(); // считывает высоту
            cx = w / 2;
            cy = h / 2;
            // для ориентации экрана
            if (w > h) {
                radius = h / 8;
            } else {
                radius = w / 8;
            }

            Paint p1 = new Paint();
            p1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            p1.setColor(Color.rgb(Colo[0], 255, 255));
            canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy - h / 3, radius, p1);

            Paint p2 = new Paint();
            p2.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            p2.setColor(Color.rgb(255, Colo[1] * 2, 255));
            canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy - h / 3 + radius * 2,
                    (float) (radius * 1.5), p2);

            Paint p3 = new Paint();
            p3.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            p3.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, Colo[2] * 3));
            canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy - h / 3 + radius * 5, radius * 2, p3);

            invalidate(); // перерисовка объектов
        }
    }
}
```